# Angular pass & bindings more than one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm able to pass & binding once and able to call the callback function successfully.

However, when I tried to pass the callback function to another isolated scope directive, I'm unable to call the callback function anymore.

How can I pass & binding scope twice?

```
    .directive('demoOne', function() {
        return {
            template: '<div><div>demo one</div>' +
                            '<button ng-click="test()">demo-one</button>' + 
                            '<demo-two demotwocb="demoonecb"></demo-two>' + 
                        '</div>',
            scope: {
                demoonecb: '&',
            },
            controller: ('demoOneCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.test = function() {
                    $scope.demoonecb({
                        text: 'demonetext'
                    });
                };
            }])
        }
    })
    .directive('demoTwo', function() {
        return {
            template: '<div><button ng-click="test()">demo-two</button></div>',
            scope: {
                demotwocb: '&',
            },
            controller: ('demoTwoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.test = function() {
                    $scope.demotwocb({
                        text: 'demtwotext'
                    });
                };
            }])
        }
    });
```

template:

```
    <demo-one demoonecb="vm.demo(text)"></demo-one>
```

I have tried to pass demoonecb to  directive by

```
<demo-two demotwocb="demoonecb(text)"></demo-two>
<demo-two demotwocb="demoonecb()"></demo-two>
<demo-two demotwocb="demoonecb"></demo-two>
```

and all have failed, controller of demo-two is unable to call the callback.

Edit:

I am using '=' two way binding to pass function now and it works, but I still want to know how can I achieve this using '&' binding

Comment: What if you create a variable in parent scope then pass it to these two directives to use as callback function carrier?

Comment: You should transfer to your directives **only** function's name: `demoonecb` as shown at last code row: `<demo-two demotwocb="demoonecb"></demo-two>` **without braces and arguments**. You will execute it and specify argument object inside your directive via `$scope.test` function as you shown above.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov I tried to pass with/withour braces or arguments, unable to pass text argument from my demoTwoCtrl $scope.test function

Comment: @ManasovDaniel I am using '=' two way binding to pass function now and  it works, but I still want to know how can I achieve this using '&' binding